# How to write this IF statement in Linear programming with Big-M

Tags: python, if-statement, linear-programming

I have to define a variable based on the decision variable `(Var[i])`.
This is what I want to express:

```
if var[i] >= 0, b[i] = 1.08; else b[i] = 0.91
```

What I wrote was :

```
var=LpVariable.dicts("Var", df.index, lowBound=-2, upBound=2, cat="Continuous")

b={}
for i in df.index:
    if var[i] >= 0.0:
       b[i] = 1.08
    else:
       b[i] = 0.91
```

However, it turned out that all `b[i]` were `1.08...`; 
I searched for the problems, and found that it should be replaced by "Big M" method. But I still can't catch how to derive it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of implementing this.

Here is a way using binary variables δ. For simplicity, I am dropping here the index i for all variables. First, assume we have good bounds on x, e.g. L ≤ x ≤ U (with L<0). Then we can state:

```
 x ≤ -ε + δ M1
 x ≥ -(1-δ) M2
 b = 1.08 δ + 0.91(1-δ)
 δ ∈ {0,1}
 x ∈ [L,U] (with L<0)
```

where ε≥0 is a small constant (e.g. ε=0.0001). In practice, I just use ε=0 in these cases. (This essentially lets the solver decide what happens at x=0; that means it will pick the most profitable choice). The big-M constants M1 and M2 can be set to:

```
 M1 = ε+U
 M2 = -L
```

More advanced systems will allow SOS1 variables. With a SOS1 approach, we no longer need big-M constants or good bounds. Read the manual of your LP/MIP solver or modeling tool to find out if this is supported.